# Not possible to break/split div into two divs?

Tags: jquery, split

Trying a way to split a div into two divs at a certain point by inserting end tag and start tag but javascript seems to adjust for this and switch the order of the tags...is there any other way?

https://jsfiddle.net/dn55u8rx/5/

```
$(".inner").before('ENDPAGE</div><div class="page">');
```

Comment: Instead of `before`, try `insertBefore`

Comment: What is the desired result? I can't really make that up from your question...

Comment: Do you want to split them vertically? Horizontally? Change width? Height?

Comment: Please excuse not being clear, I want to split a div with a certain class into two divs with this certain class, horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be a good solution for you?

```js
$(".inner").html('<div class="page" style="border:1px solid yellow">1</div><div class="page" style="border:1px solid yellow">2</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer" style="border:1px solid red">
<div class="page"  style="border:1px solid blue">
TEST
<div class="inner"  style="border:1px solid green">
TEST2
</div>
TEST3
</div>
</div>
```